# azure-ad-b2c - Incorrect error message on verification code

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

In Azure AD B2C, when I try signing up for a new account and enter the verification code once it has expired (post the 3 minute window); I get an error message – “too many incorrect attempts”.
However the message should be something like – “ code expired; retry”.

How can I set this error message correctly?
I’m using the default error page in SUSI policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [language customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-language-customization) to configure certain messages.

Unfortunately, I can only find that message in the SignUp policy.

```
{
  "ElementType": "UxElement",
  "ElementId": null,
  "StringId": "ver_fail_no_retry",
  "Override": false,
  "Value": "You've made too many incorrect attempts. Please try again later."
},
```